# Flexing in space habitats

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to identify the name of a science fiction book I read in the mid-1990s.

The plot loosely revolves around future humanity having spread or migrated to vast space city habitats. Very athletic humanoid creatures have been bred or created with hyper-violent temperaments. They have the ability to keep their composure most of the time, except for their periodic need to **flex** where they will go on violent killing sprees - much to the alarm of everyone involved.

What I remember is that the story is told from the point of view of one of these creatures and involves a lot of hopping between different space cities and ensuing adventures.

Would anyone have any idea what book this may be?

Answer (score 5):

### This might be "Humanoids from the Deep"

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080904/

**PLOT SUMMARIZATION:**
Scientific experiments backfire and produce horrific mutations: half man, half fish, which terrorize a small fishing village by killing the men and raping the women.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't it. The story takes place in city habitats in space, so fairly more high-tech.

Comment: Don't know your lost story but I've just got myself a copy of 'Humanoids from the deep' . I'd never heard of it until this question. Thank you Invoker